# Why would be an IP address in URL enclosed in square brackets and what HTTP host header is sent?

Tags: curl, url, minio, pre-signed-url

I have a really specific issue that I thought is a bug, but it appears not. I am using minIO client to generate presigned URL for AWS S3 object. What I get from that tool is an URL that starts like this:

```
http://[192.168.0.1]/bucket_name/object_name
```

Thinking it is a bug, I replaced the brackets with regular expression, but then the URL would not work (hostname is part of the AWS signature). Looking deeper into it, I see this in URL specification ([RFC 3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.2.2)):

> The host subcomponent of authority is identified by an IP literal
> encapsulated within square brackets, an IPv4 address in dotted-
> decimal form, or a registered name.

Never heard of this. If I pass this to `curl -g` I get an error, as I'd expect:

```
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

Curiously, after a lot of digging I know for a fact that at some point in time, it worked.

So the question is basically, is this really valid and if it is, what does the corresponding `Host` header look like for such URL. I need to fetch from that URL without altering it.

Comment: *" I replaced the brackets with regular expression*" ??? Please edit your question to show the exact text of the code that is failing. Did you try just removing the `[]` chars? That would be a reasonable looking IP address for your local network. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read a bit further down in [RFC 3986§3.2.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.2.2), the only valid `IP-literal` is one that contains an IPv6 (or later) address:

> ```
> IP-literal = "[" ( IPv6address / IPvFuture  ) "]"
> ```

A bit before that, there is explicit verbiage indicating these brackets are only applicable for instances where an IPv6 address is present as the Host:

> A host identified by an Internet Protocol literal address, version 6 [RFC3513] or later, is distinguished by enclosing the IP literal within square brackets ("[" and "]").  This is the only place where square bracket characters are allowed in the URI syntax.

Unless the tool usually returns an IPv6 address, this is likely indeed a bug (or some sort of misconfiguration somewhere).